# Using an object as key for NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a bunch of `Lesson`s and the class works great. There is a view controller that works with these lessons. This controller needs to know the upload status of a `lesson` so we have a NSDictionary with the `Lesson` as key and an `NSNumber` having the percent of upload status.

This is a problem because after you insert a `Lesson` you want to later do a lookup on that same `Lesson` (perhaps in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`) to get the progress. This does not work because keys are copied in NSDictionary.

Is it good form to save and fetch keys with something like this:

```
NSNumber *key = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:[obj hash]];
[dict setObject:@"... upload progress" forKey:key];
```

Or there a better approach?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I have used this technique many times in the past, and have had great success by wrapping the key-objects into an NSValue:

```
NSValue *myKey = [NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:anInstance];
id anItem =[myDict objectForKey:myKey];
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsvalue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSValue/valueWithNonretainedObject:

(forgive the formatting; I'm on iPhone. I'll format later :-)

Comment: Works 100%, I am now using this. Thank you.

Comment: `NSMapTable` is also an option. It behaves like an `NSDictionary` but allows weak references to its keys on top of other options.

Comment: I have a simple code sample for `NSMapTable` below.

Answer (score 5):

Going solely off the sentence: "This does not work because keys are copied in NSDictionary." Have you tried implementing `-isEqual:` and `-hash` in your Lesson class? I'm willing to bet that if the Lesson you use for lookup and the copied one in the dictionary as a key evaluate `-isEqual:` to `YES` when compared, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 5):

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];           
NSMapTable *dict = [NSMapTable weakToStrongObjectsMapTable];
[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1234] forKey:view];
NSNumber *x = [table objectForKey:view];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the lesson has a unique number (or identifier) make that the key. Using a NSMutableDictionary, you can then later update the dictionary but writing a new number with a higher value (as the Lession updates) but the same key.